clarification on Variance formula
It is possible to calculate the variance using two formulas. one is dividing by n and the other is dividing by n-1. Thus, my question is that
is the result we get by dividing (n) and (n-1) the same?
Example

Obviously not the same.

@Lucenaposition,  if the numerator is zero, then it doesn't matter what the denominator is. Otherwise sure.

You definitively should look at this video on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xslIhnquFoE), and visit the website (which explains the "mistery of n-1" in 3 parts) here (https://www.civil.uwaterloo.ca/brodland/EasyStats/EasyStats/Mystery_of_n-1_%28Part_1%29.html). This hould answer al your questions, and more.

If the observations are all equal, the two calculations give the same result (zero). Otherwise, the calculations will differ.
PROOF
(This proof assumes at least two (possibly equal) $X_i$. Without that assumption, the $n-1$ formula does not even make sense.)
Define $t = \overset{n}{\underset{i = 1}{\sum}}\left(X_i - \bar X\right)^2$. Then define $\hat\sigma^2_p=\dfrac{t}{n-p}$.
First, let all $X_i$ be equal. Then $\bar X = X_i$, so $t=0$, and $\hat\sigma^2_0 = \hat\sigma^2_1 = 0$. This proves the first part.
Next, let the $X_i$ not all be equal. Then $t \ne 0$. If $\hat\sigma^2_p = \hat\sigma^2_{p^{\prime}}$, then $\dfrac{t}{n-p} = \dfrac{t}{n-p^{\prime}}$. Cross-multiply.
$$
tn - tp^{\prime} = tn - tp\\
n - p^{\prime} = n - p\\
p = p^{\prime}
$$
This shows that, for $t\ne0$, $\hat\sigma^2_p = \hat\sigma^2_{p^{\prime}}$ implies $p = p^{\prime}$.
Taking the contrapositive, for $t\ne0$, $p\ne p^{\prime}$ implies $\hat\sigma^2_p \ne \hat\sigma^2_{p^{\prime}}$. As $0\ne 1$, $\hat\sigma^2_0 \ne \hat\sigma^2_1$.

The proof can be made much simpler division (where defined) is bijective (because its inverted by re-multiplication) and $n\ne n-1,$ QED.
